# gcc 4.5.1 virtual inheritance issue

Tags: c++, virtual-inheritance

Let's start from code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

struct God{
    God(){_test = 8;}
    virtual ~God(){}
    int _test;
};

struct Base1 : public virtual God{
    //Base1(){std::cout << "Base1::Base1" << std::endl;}  //enable this line to fix problem
    virtual ~Base1(){}
};

struct Base2 : public virtual Base1{
    virtual ~Base2(){}
};

struct A1 : public virtual Base2{
    A1(){std::cout << "A1:A1()" << std::endl;}
    virtual ~A1(){};
};

struct A2 : public virtual Base2{
    A2(){std::cout << "A2:A2()" << std::endl;}
    virtual ~A2(){};
};


struct Derived: public virtual A1, public virtual A2{
    Derived():Base1(){std::cout << "Derived::Derived()" << std::endl;}
    Derived(int i){std::cout << "Derived(i)::Derived(i)" << std::endl;}         
    virtual ~Derived(){}
};


int main(){

    God* b1 = new Derived();
    std::cout << b1->_test << std::endl;    //why it prints 0?

    God* b2 = new Derived(5);
    std::cout << b2->_test << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with GCC 4.5.1 and 4.6.1
The only difference between constructors of Derived class is that first one explicitly states which Base1 constructor should be called. 
I would expect that both cout in main() print 8. Unfortunately the first one prints 0!.

**Why?**

If I enable explicit definition of Base1 constructor it fixes the problem. 
If I remove virtual inheritance in Derived class definition (class Derived: public A1, public A2) it works as well.
Is it expected behaviour?

The issue is not observable under GCC 3.4.4 or Microsoft compiler (VS)

Comment: I get "8" with gcc 3.4.6

Comment: Certainly looks like you've triggered a gcc bug to me.

Answer (score 1):

This must be a compiler bug. I also tested GCC 4.2.1 and the result is 8 both cases.

Answer (score 1):

I tested with several older flavours (up to 4.3 - which works) - don't have a 4.4 series to hand (will test in the morning), but I agree, this appears to be a bug (and not in the db), probably worth raising it.

I notice though that if you change the first relationship (`Base1` to `God` from virtual to non-virtual), then the example works as expected. I guess this depends on your needs, whether you will directly call the ctor of `God` from the most derived class (though I've never seen this approach before...)